# How to scale sprites in libgdx?

Tags: android, libgdx

I made an app in libGDX. I have a sprite which is 256*256 pixels. But this is too big, so I want to scale it down to 160*160 pixels. How could I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using a version of the draw method in the SpriteBatch class, which is

```
batch.draw(Sprite, float x, float y, float  width, float  height)
```

So you can scale to 160 * 160 pixels by calling:

```
batch.begin();
batch.draw(yourSprite, 0, 0, 160, 160);
batch.end();
```

You should note that scaling is an expensive operation especially for low -end devices and should be used when absolutely necessary. Ideally, you should resize all your images/textures before using them in your project.

Comment: Originally I made my app for 1920*1080 pixels and my object was 160*160. Now - to support different screen sizes - the object's width and height is 160* (Gdx.graphics.getWidth()/1920), so the object isn't too big on low density screens. Now the sprite's size is 256*256, because I want my app to look good on high density screens (like Quad Hd). But I think that I'll probably create different textures for different densities. Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of manually drawing the sprite using `batch.draw(sprite...)` you can use `sprite.draw(Batch batch)`. Using the sprite's own method will do all of the object's transformations for you, which makes things a bit easier to handle. This is of course assuming you are using the actual [Sprite](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html) class to hold your texture, which I would highly recommend.